# Can't reinstall libmount1 or util-linux

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I accidentally compiled and installed util-linux on `Ubuntu Trusty`, now I'm trying to recover the overridden files with apt-get,

But when I try to re-install `libmount1` and `util-linux`,

```
apt-get install -f libmount1 util-linux --reinstall
```

It says

```
Reinstallation of libmount1 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of util-linux is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

How can I bypass this?

Comment: If you run `apt-get update`, does it work? Is the `install` command above still failing afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install them manually with dpkg.

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmount1
>
> http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/util-linux